# Something messed with my answers backslashes and newlines

Tags: bug, answers, markdown, code

[My answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70035/15616) is not displayed correctly. The internet archive has a [correct version of the first revision](http://web.archive.org/web/20130302102612/https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69997/how-to-write-an-mn-matrix-in-latex), see [this screenshot from archive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzWSd.png). The difference is that now, though I didn't do any changes to that part, it says

```
\[
M=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\        3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\      \end{bmatrix}
\]
```

instead of

```
\[
M=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
  \end{bmatrix}
\]
```

Why?

Comment: The edit history for the question shows the backslashes missing in the first version (http://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/51bd0f7c-a9a7-42a9-bee4-38686e3178d2/view-source). If they were there that suggests an issue with the backend database: one for the 'Powers'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The linked question has now been fixed (along with ~11,000 similarly corrupted postings)

see

[Community effort in fixing the double backslashes issue](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7317/1090)

For a summary of how this got fixed in the end.